# Project reactor: subscribeOn() after Flux.create() doesn't consistently use the scheduler thread

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, project-reactor

When I run the code below, I expect to see both subscribers getting their own elastic thread.  However, they do not consistently do so.  For example, on my system if I uncomment the `thread.Sleep(100)` line, my print statements indicate that the consumers are receiving their data on the main thread.  If leave it commented, I see the output I would expect: each consumer receives its data on its own elastic thread.  Why do I see this nondeterministic behavior?  How am I abusing the API?

```
    List<FluxSink<String>> holder = new ArrayList<>();
    ConnectableFlux<String> connect = Flux. 
           <String>create(holder::add).replay();
    connect.connect();
    Flux<String> flux = connect.subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic());
    FluxSink<String> sink = holder.get(0);

    flux.subscribe(c -> {
       System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ", " + 
         "consumer 1 says " + c);
    });

    flux.subscribe(c -> {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ", " + 
          "consumer 2 says " + c);
    });
    // When uncommented, subscribers receive on elastic threads; else,
    // on the main thread, as if I had chosen schedulers.immediate()
    //
    // Thread.sleep(100);
    sink.next("Hi!");

    sink.complete();

    Thread.sleep(1000);

    //output with Thread.sleep(100):
    // main, consumer 1 says Hi!
    // main, consumer 2 says Hi!
    //
    //output without Thread.sleep(100):
    // elastic-2, consumer 1 says Hi!
    // elastic-3, consumer 2 says Hi!
```

What I'd like to achieve is a hot stream with multiple subscribers and each subscriber on its own thread.

Comment: shouldn't you chain the subscribeOn _before_ the replay/connect() ? otherwise the connectable flux has no notion of the subscribeOn